# Pull configuration settings from an API in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In my `Startup.cs` class I have the following

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("cookie", options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "cookie name";
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "the authority URL";

            options.ClientId = "the client identifier";
            options.ClientSecret = "super secret";

            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("api");
        });
```

And contrary to having hardcoded values, I would like to call an API to get them. The API will return a model named `FooAuthenticationConfiguration`.

Comment: How do you want to extract it in Startup.cs? Is it to read the configuration from the json configuration file, then encapsulate it into a method, and then call the API to use in Startup.cs?

Comment: I have to call an API endpoint that returns a DTO which will contain the values I need. Values I will use then to replace the placeholders.

Comment: MS follow the options pattern (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for all configuration. You can implement an `IConfigureOptions<T>` service to customise any options object after `ConfigureServices`, using other services from DI.

Comment: Also, put a breakpoint in any of your `options => ` lamda's, look at the call stack when you hit them, and you'll see that these callbacks are invoked during the first access to `IOptions<T>.Value`. As would any `IConfigureOptions<T>` service.

Comment: Another option would be to make a configuration provider so that the values will then be available through IConfiguration like everything else.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response. Any sample you may want to share?

Comment: You stated a goal. But what's preventing you from accomplishing the goal? Why can't you do what you stated in the question? Did you attempt it? What problem did you run into with your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

This is the `Program.cs` from a Blazor WASM but should work similarly

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(c =>
{
    c.ProviderOptions.ConfigurationEndpoint = $"{builder.Configuration["ApiBaseUri"]}/_configuration/auth";
});
```

And then the `Controller` in your `Api` would look like this..

```
[ApiController]
[Route("_configuration")]
public class ConfigurationController
    : ControllerBase
{
    readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public ConfigurationController(
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("auth")]
    public IActionResult GetAuthConfiguration()
    {
        
        var settings = new Dictionary<string, object?>()
        {
            { "authority", configuration.GetValue<string>("oAuth:Authority") },            
            { "scope", "openid profile" },
            { "response_type", "code" },
            { "redirect_uri", "myUrl" }
        };

        return new JsonResult(settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I undestood correctly what you want to do, but tell me if this works for you:

In Startup.cs, create a method like:

```
        private async Task GetConfiguration()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var Response = await client.GetAsync("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");
        }
```

Convert the ConfigureServices into an Async Method and calls in the beggining the GetConfiguration() like this:

```
    public async void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        await GetConfiguration();
        //....
    }
```